# Present one bulleted list for each row in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
 name1 |  dllink1 | dltarget1 | dllink1Text | link2 | dltarget2 | dllink2Text | link3 | dltarget3 | dllink3Text | ... | link10
 name2 |  dllink1 | dltarget1 | dllink1Text | link2 | dltarget2 | dllink2Text | NULL  | NULL      | NULL        | ... | link10
 ...   |    ...   | ...       |    ...      | ...   | ...       | ...         | ...   | ...
```

I want to output a bulleted list of the links for each of the names as long as the link is not NULL:

```
<dl>name1<dl/>
    <li><a href="dllink1" target="dltarget1>dllink1Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="dllink2" target="dltarget2>dllink2Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="dllink3" target="dltarget2>dllink3Text</a></li>

<dl>name2<dl/>
    <li><a href="dllink1" target="dltarget1>dllink1Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="dllink2" target="dltarget2>dllink2Text</a></li>

<dl>name3<dl/>
    <li><a href="dllink1" target="dltarget1>dllink1Text</a></li>
...
```

('dltarget(x)' is `_self`, `_blank` etc. in the table)

What is the best and most correct approach to achieve this? Fetching values, i.e. `$row['name']` in a `while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($rs))` is relatively easy for a novice to learn, but this turned out somewhat of a challenge..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off your SQL table is not properly normalized.  You should split it out into two tables (this will make it far easier to extend, maintain and understand) - say links and link_groups (for the sake of argument since I am not totally aware of the context).  Your links table can contain "href", "target", "title" and "link_group_id" as the foriegn key to associate your link with your link_group and your link_groups can have an auto incremented "id" as the primary key and a "name" field to identify the group.

There are a number of ways to approach the problem once this has been done and one simple (albeit a little noisy) approach would be as follows...

Note, the alternative PHP syntax in second block (this is assuming front end code).  You can code it however you like - (i.e. put PHP in traditional form in one entire block).

```
<?php 
$links = []; // only use this alternative array syntax if using PHP 5.4+ 

// your recordset for links
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $links[$rs->link_group_id][] = $row;
}
?>

<!-- your recordset for link groups -->
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)): ?>
    <dl>    
      <dt><?php echo($row->name); ?></dt>
      <?php foreach ($links[$row->id] as $link): ?>
        <dd>
          <a href="<?php echo($link->href); ?>"
             target="<?php echo($link->target); ?>"><?php echo($link->title); ?></a>
        </dd>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! However "$links[$rs->link_group_id][] = $row;" give an error:  "...unexpected '-', expecting ']'"?  (PHP 5.4.34)

Comment: Nevermind the above, my fault - typo. Got it to list the names, but no links. Something wrong in the foreach: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". If I change it to foreach ((array)$links[$row->id] as $link), then no error, but still no links below the names.

Comment: Why voted down? Got it working, had to change "$links[$rs->link_group_id][] = $row;" to "$links[$row->link_group_id][] = $row;". So thanks, works great.